# Asserting the identity of an application in App Engine Python 3.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-3.7

App Engine's Python 2.7 runtime had a very convenient way of [asserting the identity](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/) of an application to another App Engine application.

As described in the above link, using the `app_identity` library of the `google.appengine.api` package I was able to obtain and insert the `auth_token` into the `urlfetch` headers. When receiving requests I could verify the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header info.

I understand `urlfetch` and the `google.appengine.api` package are not  available in the Python 3.7 runtime.

My app consists of several GAE projects, so I used this method to verify the identity of api calls between **my** projects (i.e so I do not need it for external APIs / services). What would be the recommended approach of doing this in App Engine's Python 3.7 runtime?